# How to Get all row Parents of mysql table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that returns all of the Id's for the parents of a given id.  Here is what I've got so far, and for all intents and purposes, the table consists of two columns, id and ParentID.  The results of the current code is that it doesn't seem to get the ParentID from the table, it just tries to add the passed in id twice to the temporary table which then fails.  Where did I go wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `mydb`.`Test` (IN id int)
BEGIN
DECLARE parentId INT;
DECLARE n INT;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS _1067_parents;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _1067_parents (
node_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  );
set n = 0;
set parentId := id;

get_parents_loop: LOOP
     set parentId := (select ParentID from mydb.myTable where TDOID = parentId);

    IF parentId is NULL THEN
      LEAVE get_parents_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO _1067_parents(node_id) Values (parentId);

END LOOP get_parents_loop;

 SELECT *
    FROM _1067_parents;

end
```

Comment: what is wrong with this? (error messages, wrong data, etc...)

Comment: I added additional information about what it's currently doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeed3/1)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
create table `MyTable`(`id` int primary key, `parentid` int)
//

insert `MyTable` (`id`, `parentid`) values
  (1, null), (2, 1), (3, 2)
//

CREATE PROCEDURE `Test` (IN cid int)
BEGIN
DECLARE parId INT;
DECLARE curId INT;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS _1067_parents;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _1067_parents (
node_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  );

set curId := cid;
get_parents_loop: LOOP
    set parId := null;

    set parId = (select parentid from MyTable where id = curId);

    IF parId is NULL THEN
      LEAVE get_parents_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO _1067_parents(node_id) Values (parId);
    set curId := parId;

END LOOP get_parents_loop;


 SELECT *
    FROM _1067_parents;

end
//

show create procedure test;
```

**Query 1**:

```
call test(3)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeed3/1/0)**:

```
| NODE_ID |
-----------
|       1 |
|       2 |
```

Comment: Gave that a shot and it returns an empty table

Comment: Worked great!  What did you change from your last post?

Comment: @TChadwick mostly syntax and variable names wich interfered with column names